# Bottom border runs away when hovering button with box-shadow in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Bottom border moves down and down again in IE9 when hovering/unhovering the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      .btn:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b1b3b4;
      }
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black;">

      <div style="width: 110%; height: 20px;">
        Wide content causing horizontal scrolling....
      </div>

      <button class="btn">Hover Me</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/6353/

Is it a known IE9 issue? How do I work that around?

Comment: you should try adding this inside your '<head>' tags: '<meta content='IE=9' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>'

Comment: @Xarcell It does not help. Without this meta the page gets rendered in IE9 mode as well anyways.

Comment: why don't you just put a bottom margin on the .btn class?

Comment: Do you want a jquery or javascript code or only css ?

Comment: @Anobik jquery/javascript solution is also OK

Comment: I checked out the code in Google chrome and it is giving the border effect. and did not modify any code. that might hamper your divs and their display. Then checked in Ie9 . and the border was not flowing away. Check and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Option 1 (change html slightly):

```
<div style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 110%; height: 20px;">Wide content causing horizontal scrolling...</div>
    <span><button class="btn">Hover Me</button></span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10615/

Option 2 (with provided html, using js):

```
$('.btn').hover(function () {
    var $btn = $(this);
    var originalPosition = $btn.css('position');
    $btn.css('position', 'fixed');
    // this.offsetHeight is needed to trigger browser reflow.
    this.offsetHeight;
    $btn.css('position', originalPosition);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10617/

Comment: Thanks, giving bounty here as these two options are the most practical solutions for me (they do not break existing styling I have). I will accept an answer later (I consider accepting apaul's option 3 or Anobic's answer, as they look to have similar ideas as option 1 and option 2 here relatively).

Comment: :'( I did not get the bounty :'( :P Kidding :D

Answer (score 3):

Put `display:block` at the `.btn:hover`.

Guess that will fix it!

```
.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b1b3b4;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it does. But still I need the button to be an inline element (in fact currently it is inline-block), so I can place several buttons in a row without extra markup.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**
Setting a height for the scrollable div seems to solve the problem:

**[Working Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10463/)**

```
<div style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black; height:65px;">
    <div style="width: 110%; height: 20px;">Wide content causing horizontal scrolling...</div>
    <button class="btn">Hover Me</button>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**
Use `overflow-x:scroll;` rather than `overflow:auto;`:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10467/)**

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 110%; height: 20px;">Wide content causing horizontal scrolling....</div>
    <button class="btn">Hover Me</button>
</div>
```

## Option 3:

**Probably the best option as it allows the box-shadow to be visible in IE9.**
Wrap the button in a div with class `.btn` rather than placing the class directly on the button.

[**Working Example 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10515/)

```
.btn {
    display:inline;
}
.btn:hover {
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b1b3b4;
}

<div style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black;padding:2px;">
    <div style="width: 110%; height: 20px;">Wide content causing horizontal scrolling...</div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button>Hover Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button>Hover Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button>Hover Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Option 4:**
Just for laughs...

**[Working Example 4](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10470/)**

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <div id="noIE"><a href="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/">Please download a Real Browser!</a>
        <br><sub>Internet Explorer is hateful non-compliant browser that kicks puppies... </sub>
    </div>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Option 1 does not work as in my case containers have dynamic content and need to expand base on its' content, option 2 - interesting, but in most of the cases there is no overflow and scroller is not desired, option 3 is equivalent to Ryan's answer with display: block, option 4 - is the best one! :)

Comment: @Andrey have you removed margin from .btn in option3? 
I think, that is what you want.

Comment: @EugineJoseph Thanks, the margin was a relic from a previous method that I forgot to remove... edited to correct.

Answer (score 1):

To correct this, change: `overlow: auto` to `overflow: visible` and that should so it.

Comment: hm, I still have a requirement to have scrollbars in the container. I can't really remove "overflow: auto" from all the elements containing buttons, it would make a big mess.

Answer (score 1):

You got yourself a really weird bug there sir. And it definitely a bug, if you use ie9-mode on a ie10, this will not happen.

I couldn't figure it out why but it seems to go back to its original state if you resize the window manually. Maybe you can fake this with javascript?

Another thing i discovered was that if you set a `:hover {zoom: 1}` on the element with the scroll, it "reset" itself when hovering of it. maybe someone can use this to figure out why it acts like it does.

fiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10599/

Answer (score 0):

please try this css:

```
.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0px 1px #b1b3b4;
}

<div style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 110%; height: 80px;">Wide content causing horizontal scrolling....</div>
    <button class="btn">Hover Me</button>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/10472/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a height of 100% to the div should fix your issue

```
<div style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black;height: 100%">
   <div style="width: 110%; height: 20px;">Wide content causing horizontal scrolling....</div>
   <button class="btn">Hover Me</button>
</div>
```

Here is the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c2sBp/

Comment: Can someone explain why my answer was down-voted? It'll be helpful to understand where was I wrong. Cheers.  :)

Comment: It wasn't me, but maybe someone decided to downvote as the answer looks as a duplicate (setting height value solves the issue as described in option 1 of apaul's answer). Upvoting this since it's not an exact duplicate (height is set in % vs px in apaul's answer).

Answer (score 0):

I checked this in Ie9 and did not find that border bottom expanding.
please give a try. and Let me know

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hover demo</title>
  <style>
  .btn{
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b1b3b4;
      }

      .noBtn{
      box-shadow: none;
      }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black;" >

      <div style="width: 110%; height: 20px;">

        Wide content causing horizontal scrolling....
      </div>
      <button id="hover">Hover Me</button>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
try{

    $('#hover').hover(function () {

    $("#hover").addClass('btn');
    $("#hover").removeClass('noBtn');

});

$('#hover').mouseleave(function () {

    $("#hover").removeClass('btn');
    $("#hover").addClass('noBtn');


        });
}catch(e){
alert(e);

}
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know after trying.

Comment: You can use class "btn" and $".btn" in place of "#hover"